# Adding facelet taglib to Adf application

Tags: jsf, ckeditor, facelets, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

In my Adf application I need to use a javascript component called ckeditor (http://ckeditor.com/). Ideally I would like to use it on a facelet page (not a jsp page). It seems like this can be achieved by using ck-jsf-editor (https://code.google.com/p/ck-jsf-editor/). The problem is that I can't figure out how to add this library/taglib to my Adf application.

Anyone knows the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In JDeveloper, you need to add the JAR that contains the JSF component to the project properties under the JSP tag libraries section.
If you are on JDeveloper 11.1.2 or 12c then your ADF application can already use facelets.